# Does CSR1012 need an external non-volatile memory for this application?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, firmware, update

I am building a IoT device in which  data is fed from I2C to [CSR1012 BLE IC](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/csr1012) and the CSR1012 then transmits the data. CSR1012 is programmed as a master MCU.

I need over-the-air update capability to push any future firmware update on this device. I am not clear on whether or not I need an external non-volatile memory like EEPROM or I2C flash to make implement over-the-air firmware update feature.

This is just to ensure that if i need to push firmware updates, I do not need to physically connect these devices to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

When devices come with FOTA (Firmware over the air) than you don't have to add anything externally.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? The CSR1012 schematics always seem to show an external EEPROM or flash to enable OTA.

Comment: Then this BLE transceiver needs external storage for FOTA.